# How to use valadoc?

Tags: documentation-generation, vala

I am currently writing a library in Vala.

I have come to a point where I would like to generate some documentation from my sources.

`valadoc` seems to be the right tool to do this, but there is not much information on how to use it, the manpage is very short.

I tried to run it with `valadoc -o doc src/*.{vala,vapi}` which gives me these error messages:

```
unixodbc.vala:21.7-21.9: error: The namespace name `Gee' could not be found
unixodbc.vala:40.9-40.27: error: The type name `Map' could not be found
unixodbc.vala:42.30-42.48: error: The type name `Map' could not be found
unixodbc.vala:40.9-40.27: error: The type name `Map' could not be found
unixodbc.vala:40.9-40.27: error: The type name `Map' could not be found
unixodbc.vala:40.9-40.27: error: The type name `Map' could not be found
unixodbc.vala:80.63-80.81: error: The type name `Map' could not be found
unixodbc.vala:98.9-98.25: error: The type name `ArrayList' could not be found
unixodbc.vala:99.3-99.19: error: The type name `ArrayList' could not be found
unixodbc.vala:110.4-110.22: error: The type name `Map' could not be found
unixodbc.vala:178.9-178.24: error: The type name `ArrayList' could not be found
unixodbc.vala:180.17-180.32: error: The type name `ArrayList' could not be found
unixodbc.vala:187.10-187.25: error: The type name `ArrayList' could not be found
Failed: 13 error(s), 0 warning(s)
```

As it seems `valadoc` was designed to be run on all dependencies as well?

How can I get this to work for my library?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to pass `--pkg gee-0.10` (or whatever version you are using), just like valac.  See the `valadoc --help` and the man page for a list of options and their descriptions.  Many of the options you'll need are the same as those you would pass to valac.

Comment: Ouch, I saw the `--pkg` option, but didn't get the association of `valac` and `valadoc`. This makes a lot more sense now.