# How to add status icon to WingPanel in Elementary OS Luna?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gtk, glade, vala

In Elementary OS Luna (or Ubuntu), how do I add an application Icon to the WingPanel (the top bar on the desktop that displays status icons like Wi-Fi connection status, Sound properties, and the Date and Time, for example?

[image]

I am using the Vala programming language.

Comment: Well, the source code is on launchpad: https://launchpad.net/wingpanel You should read the source code and you can of course also take a look at the source of the existing wingpanel applets.

Comment: So there is no documentation for this?

Comment: Since elementary OS is quite young and developers (in general) don't exactly love to write documentation, you should expect that you often have to dig through the source code.

Comment: Have you tried taking this to the developer chat? http://elementaryos.org/developer/chat You can also ask questions on their launchpad projects.

Comment: BTW: Do you know valadoc? It generates API documentation from Vala source code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19211187/how-to-use-valadoc

Comment: Hey @JensMühlenhoff, thanks for the links. Yeah I have tried the Dev chat but I really don't like having to rely on people to help me with everything - I much prefer docs. But I am finding it a little difficult to find documentation (I'm new to Linux - I've been creating apps for windows since 2005) - thanks for your help :)

Comment: Ohhh, so *that's* what valadoc is. Nice!

Comment: No Problem. When you find out how to do it, you should answer your own question here, so future visitors of the question can learn from it. You can even accept your own answer on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There used to be an example on the https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Vala/Examples page dealing with adding a tray icon, which might solve this.  I wasn't able to find the link to that, so I'll provide the source code and compile command here.

```
using Gtk;

public class Main {

  class AppStatusIcon : Window {
    private StatusIcon trayicon;
    private Gtk.Menu menuSystem;

    public AppStatusIcon() {
      /* Create tray icon */
      trayicon = new StatusIcon.from_stock(Stock.HOME);
      trayicon.set_tooltip_text ("Tray");
      trayicon.set_visible(true);

      trayicon.activate.connect(about_clicked);

      create_menuSystem();
      trayicon.popup_menu.connect(menuSystem_popup);
    }

    /* Create menu for right button */
    public void create_menuSystem() {
      menuSystem = new Gtk.Menu();
      var menuAbout = new ImageMenuItem.from_stock(Stock.ABOUT, null);
      menuAbout.activate.connect(about_clicked);
      menuSystem.append(menuAbout);
      var menuQuit = new ImageMenuItem.from_stock(Stock.QUIT, null);
      menuQuit.activate.connect(Gtk.main_quit);
      menuSystem.append(menuQuit);
      menuSystem.show_all();
    }

    /* Show popup menu on right button */
    private void menuSystem_popup(uint button, uint time) {
      menuSystem.popup(null, null, null, button, time);
    }

    private void about_clicked() {
      var about = new AboutDialog();
      about.set_version("0.0.0");
      about.set_program_name("Tray");
      about.set_comments("Tray utility");
      about.set_copyright("vala");
      about.run();
      about.hide();
    }
  }

  public static int main (string[] args) {
    Gtk.init(ref args);
    var App = new AppStatusIcon();
    App.hide();
    Gtk.main();
    return 0;
  }
}
```

The compile command that runs this is: `valac icon_test.vala -o build_test --pkg gtk+-3.0`

I'm not certain that this will add it to the panel the way that you want, but it *does* create traditional tray icons.  Good luck.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @Andrew I'm looking at your answer now.