# Correct way for making documentation in Vala projects

Tags: linux, gtk3, gnome, vala

What's the common approach for making documentation to Vala projects in Gnome community? (I am considering valadoc but haven't found the current status of that tool)

Answer (score 1):

`valadoc` is still current, you [just pass the same arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19211187/how-to-use-valadoc) as you would with the vala compiler.